# PHP: How to set dynamic titles while auto_prepend_file is being used?

Tags: php

The title says it all: I want the page to determine the title, but the title is being set before the page is being read (I think). Is there a way to accomplish this, or am I doomed to include the header on each individual page?

Here's what I have:

php.ini:

```
auto_prepend_file = "header.php"
```

header.php:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($title) == false) {
        $title = "foobar";
    }
    $title = "My Site : " . $title;
?>
<title><?php echo($title) ?></title>
```

index.php

```
<?php 
    $title = "Home"; // ideally this would make the title "My Site : Home"
?>
```

Comment: The standard way to do this is to have a container file that includes the header, and you include all of your other files from there. You're not supposed to include the header file in every file (although for security purposes you might want to include some kind of basic session check).

Comment: @Ynhockey Do you know of some documentation that describes the proper way to do this?

Comment: [**Echo**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) isn't a function, it's a language construct `echo $title`

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- I like to use the parenthesis for my own readability, is there any danger in doing this?

Comment: I doubt there's a danger, there's just no need for the parentheses; while it still works, it's just 2 extra keystrokes ;)

Comment: Couldn't you just do in your `index.php` file `include 'header.php'; echo($title)`? That works.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm trying to avoid writing that on each page. For instance, let's say I have 100 php pages. I don't want to go through and write <? include 'header.php' ?> a hundred times. And what if I want to prepend something else later on? I don't want to have to rewrite it a hundred times, ya know?

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, that question's been asked before. Saw something similar to this about a month or so ago and nobody was able to give a definite answer, besides one comment being "use Wordpress" lol; it wasn't "my" comment btw ;) - So I too am unable to give you a definite answer. If I come up with anything, I'll let you know, *cheers*

Comment: P.s.: You may want to Google "if current page PHP", there's bound to be something you could use from it, which may be what you'll want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using auto_prepend_file, I would just use:

```
include 'header.php';
```

An important reason why I wouldn't use auto_prepend_file is, if you move to another server, you'll have to remember to edit the php.ini. If you just include the file, you can move your code to any server.

Also, just like Fred-ii- said, I wouldn't use parenthesis. Also, you are missing a semi-colon after the echo.

To take that a step further, I would create a file called something like $config.php or $vars.php. Include that before everything and have it define all your global variables and constants.

I would check this out: http://php.about.com/od/tutorials/ht/template_site.htm

Comment: OK, but I'm trying to avoid including header.php on every content page. It seems like that link says I'll have to include header on every page, right or did I miss something?

Comment: For this method you would have to include it on every content page. Unless you used a framework, like microMVC, and load it before or into the view. Again, the only reason I suggest not using php.ini is because you might have to switch servers or you might want more sites on this server that do not autoload the file...

Comment: +1 for good reason not using the ini file for this. If you have to include header on every page you should reconsider how your project is build. @TravisHeeter

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal answer, but I could use CGI variables to get the name of the page, then turn that into a title.

```
function get_title($page){
    $title = str_replace("/", "", $page);
    $title = str_replace("_", " ", $title);
    $title = str_replace(".php", "", $title);
    $title = ucfirst($title);
    if($title = "Index"){
        $title = "Home";
    } elseif ($title == "") {
        $title = 'Foobar';
    }
    return $title;
}

$title = get_title($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
$title = 'My Site: ' . $title;
```

Comment: This could also be expanded to look for a query string variable for a title, but I personally wouldn't want to put a title variable in every internal href.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up to my original comment, I'm posting this as an answer because while it doesn't specifically solve the problem, it addresses the underlying cause.

Disclaimer: The code below has many problems, especially security, it's not meant to be copied directly but only explains the concept.

What you need to do is have a container file that includes your headers and whatever else, and each PHP file is included from there. For example, name your container `index.php`, and have the following in it:

```
<?php
    include 'header.php';

    if ($_GET['page'])
        include $_GET['page'].'.php';

    include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Then each PHP page you have will be wrapped in the `index.php` file, and you can add whatever you want in the header file which will be included in all of your files. That way you don't have to include anything in the individual page files.

The client will access your pages with a query string, such as: `index.php?page=test`

Again, for security reasons you will still want to include basic checks in each individual file, but technically this can be avoided in you plan for this. You definitely won't need to include huge headers in each file, like MySQL connections etc. Also for security you should have stringent checks on your $_GET variables to make sure that only the pages you want can be included.

Comment: if you use this solution, please make sure you do this correctly `Also for security you should have stringest checks on your $_GET variables to make sure that only the pages you want can be included.`

Answer (score 0):

I'd define a `writeTitle` (or similar) function in the `header.php` file which you're auto_prepending:

`header.php`

```
<?php

function writeTitle($title = 'foobar') {
    $title = "My Site : " . $title;
    return '<title>' . $title . </title>';
}
```

And then you can just call the function from your page scripts instead of setting a variable:

`index.php`

```
<?php

echo writeTitle('Home');
```

Comment: But wouldn't that write the title in the content page and not the header (not in the <head> element)?

Comment: My answer was based on your `header.php` file — it depends on what else — if anything — is in your header file. PSR recommendations are for a file to declare functionality or display content ("side effects") — not to do both. You could maybe look at templating libraries.